# Why is there a discrepancy in the size shown by df and du for a mounted google drive storage account?

Tags: linux, mount, disk-usage, google-drive

I am using `cp` to copy directories from a mounted google drive storage account to disk.

I need to find out the total size of all directories to be copied from google drive to disk to know the amount of disk space needed.

The google drive storage account was mounted using google-drive-ocamlfuse. I ran both `df` and `du` commands as shown below.

`df` shows that the total size of the mounted google drive storage account is 15G and 11G is used. However, `du` shows that the total size of the .shared folder (which I assume is the "Shared with me" folder in my google drive account) is 93G.

Why is there a discrepancy in the size shown by `df` and `du` for a mounted google drive storage account?

And why is the size of the .shared (i.e. "Shared with me") folder much larger than the size of the google drive storage account shown by `df` and in the browser, when the google drive account contains the "Shared with me" folder?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
google-drive-ocamlfuse    15G   11G  4.7G  69% /home/user/cloud_storage

$ du -h --max-depth=1 cloud_storage
93G     cloud_storage/.shared
4.0K    cloud_storage/.Trash
98G     cloud_storage

$ du -h --max-depth=1 cloud_storage/.shared/
5G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderA
1G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderB
3G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderC
1G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderD
1G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderE
2G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderF
1G    cloud_storage/.shared/FolderG
20G     cloud_storage/.shared/FolderH
30G     cloud_storage/.shared/FolderI
28G     cloud_storage/.shared/FolderJ
1G     cloud_storage/.shared/FolderK
93G     cloud_storage/.shared/
```

Comment: Note to readers: There are a number of questions that are seemingly duplicates of this on the topic of "`df` vs. `du` discrepancies".  An answer should address the fact that fusefs and Google Drive is involved (which I _think_ makes this a bit different, but I might be wrong).